# Get site collections where owner is on list of email addresses from AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I`m trying to figure out a way to retrieve a list of site collections whose owners match a list of email addresses I extract from an AD group.

The following code gives me a list of email addresses stored in a variable as an array.

```
$group = "CONTOSO"
$users = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like $group} | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | 
Select-Object -Unique | 
Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |
Select-Object Mail |
Sort-Object Mail
```

I would like to get all owners of a site collection in my tenant that is on that list and output the site collection name.

However, I`ve been unable to get the owner email addresses from all site owners in our tenant let alone compare them to the extracted AD email addresses.

I tried this code to retrieve all owners of site collections in the tenant.

```
Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/ |
Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Owners"} | Select-Object Users
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Get-SPWebApplication "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/" | Get-SPSite | foreach-object { Write-host $_.Url - $_.Owner.Email}
```

Ref : [Click Here](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/get-all-sharepoint-site-collection-owners-report.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I am on SP Online and PowerShell 5 so those cmdlets do not work anymore. If I do:  <br/>

Get-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/ | foreach-object {Write-host $_.Url -$_.Owner.Email}

it returns:

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/ -Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPOSite.Owner.Email